# Check if each element in a list match with a string in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am writing a simple if else loop to check if a string match with multiple words like this:

```
if "word1" in data or "word2" in data or "word3" in data:
    ....
```

I am not sure if we have a more comprehensive way to process this kind of comparison ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if any(word in data for word in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')):
    ...
```

If you run into performance issues, you may want to convert `data` to a `set` before running the comparisons.

Comment: actually, inspectorG4dget's solution worked for another case. In mine, this is the best. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
if any(x in data for x in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')):
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not a set intersect?

```
if set(["word1", "word2","word3"]) & set(data):
    # do stuff!
```

Comment: Clever (+1), but again, don't use a list, use a tuple.  (There's no reason for a list here and a tuple is faster to generate)

Comment: and actually, `set(data).intersection(("word1","word2","word3"))` might be slightly faster as there is no need to create 2 sets for this operation.

Comment: @mgilson: I seem to be off my game with the formatting today. Thank you for cleaning up my posts (I believe this is the 2nd or 3rd one today that you have fixed the formatting in)

Comment: Shrunk & White, here I come! ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: I have to "facebook like" that comment. Alas, SO does not have that functionality. Still made me LOL, though

Comment: LOL - I'm still going for @mgilson 's fifth place on the Python tag of "top users" :)

Comment: Thank you very much, inspectorG4dget. I also used tuple as mgilson comment, and it works like a charm

Comment: Note that this won't work if `data` was a string containing "word1", "word2", etc., as substrings (which it might have been based on the OP's code).

Comment: There is one performance implication: the intersection of two sets does not shortcut in the same way as `any`.  This is probably not an issue here.